# FuelPHP Upload Class not found

Tags: class, upload, fuelphp

I am trying to upload an image using FuelPHP framework Upload class and I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'FuelPHP\Upload\Upload' not found in
>   /projects/clients/client0/web61/web/fuel/fuel/core/classes/upload.php
>   on line 90

This is the code I am using after the form is submitted:

```
Upload::process($config);

if (Upload::is_valid()) {
    Upload::save();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in `FuelPHP_1.6.1.zip` file. Update Fuel to `1.6/master` or

Edit **`composer.json`** with:

```
  "fuelphp/upload": "2.0"
to
  "fuelphp/upload": "1.*"
```

and then,

```
$ composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you don't have the [FuelPHP/Upload](https://github.com/fuelphp/upload) package installed. Have you ran:

```
composer install
```

on your root folder?

The current Upload class just translates the old class interface to the new one, as Harro describes [here](http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/comment/15504#Comment_15504).

Comment: Do you meant update composer? Yes, I did that when I've first installed fuel.

Comment: Assuming the package is installed on the correct vendor directory, have you called the Composer autoloader from the bootstrap.php

Like so:
`require APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';`

after the

`Autoloader::register();`

?